# SoftLayer API to create an ObjectStorage failed. What's wrong?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

SoftLayer developers.

When ran a script to create an Object Storage in `WDC01` in SoftLayer, it failed. I opened a ticket with SoftLayer. Then SL support suggested to post the API code and error here.

Could someone help to solve the problem?

FYI: This API has been used for long and it didn't have any issue to create an Object Storage in DAL05 yesterday.

API Code:

```
 # GET
    headers = Hash["X-Auth-Key"=>pkg_apikey,"X-Auth-User"=>pkg_username]
    url="https://#{datacenter_name}.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/"
    keys = ["x-auth-token","x-storage-url"]
    resp = utilRest.doRestWithHeaders(url,headers,"get",keys)
```

where

```
 pkg_apikey : ***************
    pkg_username : <SL account>
    datacenter_name : wdc01
```

Error:

> getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Comment: If i access to the following URL: 
https://dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/
I got 
"Unauthorized
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested."

but if access to https://wdc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/
I got "Server not found".

wdc01 is correct object storage location name?

Comment: It looks name resolution failed.
Is wdc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net correct URL?

$ ping wdc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net
ping: cannot resolve wdc01.objectstorage.softlayer.net: Unknown host

$ ping dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net
PING dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net (173.192.119.146): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.192.119.146: icmp_seq=0 ttl=239 time=175.742 ms

^C
--- dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 144.235/154.142/175.742/12.806 ms
$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this link:

https://wdc.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/

you can use the control portal to see the valid URLs

Regards

Comment: thanks.  SL support also said WDC01's object storage is wdc.objectstorage.softlayer.net. 
I'll change my API.